# Where to find a similar to C grammar as inspiration in Xtext?

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I am working on a DSP toolchain named [CrossCore Embedded Studio](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/processors-and-dsp/evaluation-and-development-software/adswt-cces.html) for SHARC Processors. The IDE is well implemented apart from the assembly language support which is very poor.

I am not sure whether or not Analog Devices will give a better support to it in a near future.

I mean, there is currently no code folding, no outlines and a very minimalistic code colouring support. I would like to *quickly* implement something more efficient and I was looking at a way to implement a new language definition in Eclipse Luna.

What I found is [xtext](/questions/tagged/xtext). So I followed the 5 and 15 minutes tutorials and read some articles about it.

I am now ready to implement my language. Because this assembly language inherits  very similar aspects from [c](/questions/tagged/c) (*i.e.* preprocessor directives, C/C++ comments, arithmetic operations and semicolons endings), I was actively looking at a C grammar example for Xtext.

Unfortunately I did not find anything yet. Sadly, I discovered that C or C++ cannot be easily described in Xtext because of the muliple language layers such as C-preprocessor and C. I will not admit defeat yet and I think I can implement something sufficent as I only require approximate syntax colouring, some code folding and outlines support.

> Where can I find helpful examples to implement such language?

Here what the SHARC assembly language looks like:

```
#include <foo.h>
#include "foo.h"
#ifdef BAR
    .segment/dm slow;
#else
    .segment/dm fast;
#endif

label:
    r1 = r2; /* Another comment */
    r3 = dm( _symbol + 0 );
    r5 = r3 + 1; // A comment
    jump(db);
       nop;
       r8 = pass r8;

another_label:
    {   // Not currently recognized by the assembly, but useful for readabily, I would like to enable code folding here...
        r2 = 3;
    }

final_label.end: nop;
.endseg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not have a long trajectory using Xtext, what I would recommend you is to search a grammar like the one you are trying to accomplish not limiting it to Xtext. As far as I know, Xtext is built on top of Antlr, which is a powerful parser generator for reading, processing, executing, or translating structured text or binary files (from [its website](http://www.antlr.org/)). Now, there are several contributions to the Antlr project in terms of grammars examples, and you can find them [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).

In that repository you can find the [C grammar written in Antlr](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4), that should be a good starting point towards the Xtext grammar; it does not vary too much.